# How to link Intel Open Image Denoise in Qt Creator and use it to denoise noisy Monte Carlo path tracing renderings?

Tags: raytracing, rendering, pathtracing, c++, denoise

I've been trying to link my the Intel Open Image Denoise libraries for about a week and still have no luck as of now. This could partly be because I am also novice in C++ stuff. So I need some help in getting it to work.

Here's what I've done so far: after compiling OIDN I moved the oidn directory to the directory where my path tracer code is and did the following in my code (C++11) which I'm working on in Qt Creator.

```
#include "oidn/include/OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp"
.
.
.
oidn::DeviceRef device = oidn::newDevice(); // this is where things break
device.commit();
```

Note that doing `#include "oidn/include/OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp"` seems to work fine because autocomplete works for oidn and shows its members. However I get the following errors which seems to be due to not linking oidn libraries.

[image]

I tried linking the libraries via `LIBS += -L"oidn/build/"` or `LIBS += -L"oidn/build/libOpenImageDenoise.so"` (as shown in the image) but I get the same errors. I also appended `-loidn` but got an error saying `"cannot find -loidn"`. I am now pretty confused on what I'm supposed to do. I'm not even sure if the errors are due to not properly linking libraries because I see people generally link libraries in C++ the same way I am trying to do it here. I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out what I need to do to get OIDN work.

Comment: maybe not that helpful but does -lOpenImageDenoise -L"oidn/build/" make any difference ? Usually -lXXX matches with a libXXX.so file. -L is for setting the search directory and should not be used to reference a library directly

Comment: @PaulHK You're correct but the issue I was experiencing had something to do with the file system. The file system had not registered many of the files and that's why the compiler couldn't find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the previous answers/comments were correct. The weird thing about my case was the symlinks of the libraries in the `build` directory were not valid and were not pointing to the right files. The output of `ls -lh /home/Warrior/Desktop/pathtracer/oidn/build` was as follow:

```
total 160K
drwxrwxr-x 4 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 apps
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  19K Feb  4 00:09 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 7 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 6.5K Feb  4 00:09 cmake_install.cmake
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 common
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 3.6K Feb  4 00:09 CPackConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 103K Feb  4 00:09 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:08 mkl-dnn
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 1.6K Feb  4 00:09 OpenImageDenoiseConfigVersion.cmake
```

But when I would go to the directory I would see the following:

[image]

What I did was instead of cloning the oidn repo somewhere else and building it, I cloned the oidn repo in `/home/Warrior/Desktop/pathtracer/` and built it there. After that I could see the correct file names/symlinks via `ls -lh` as follow. Now my program compiles and things work fine. I just had to use `LIBS += -L"oidn/build/" -lOpenImageDenoise` when compiling my code:

```
total 51M
drwxrwxr-x 4 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:14 apps
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  19K Feb  9 10:14 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 7 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:19 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 5.6K Feb  9 10:14 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 3.1K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc_sse4.h
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:14 common
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 3.3K Feb  9 10:14 CPackConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 3.7K Feb  9 10:14 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.6K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.6K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 3.1K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.6K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc_sse4.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  41K Feb  9 10:14 libcommon.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  16M Feb  9 10:17 libdnnl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 amir amir   24 Feb  9 10:19 libOpenImageDenoise.so -> libOpenImageDenoise.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 amir amir   28 Feb  9 10:19 libOpenImageDenoise.so.0 -> libOpenImageDenoise.so.1.3.0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir  34M Feb  9 10:19 libOpenImageDenoise.so.1.3.0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  37K Feb  9 10:19 libutils.a
drwxrwxr-x 2 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:17 local__core
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 104K Feb  9 10:14 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:14 mkl-dnn
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir 181K Feb  9 10:19 oidnBenchmark
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir  59K Feb  9 10:19 oidnDenoise
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir 882K Feb  9 10:19 oidnTest
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 1.6K Feb  9 10:14 OpenImageDenoiseConfigVersion.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.9K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc_sse4.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 3.1K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc_sse4.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.8K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc_sse4.h
drwxrwxr-x 2 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:17 weights
```